Can a TL431 be configured to output a negative reference voltage?
I need a negative 1.25 voltage reference to zero out an LM317's output to zero. I have been at a loss to find a 1.25 V.R.device, so I thought I could use the TL431 with a divider.
Can a TL431 be configured to output a negative ref. voltage?
Also, can a negative output be accomplished with a positive input to the TL431?
If one or both of the above questions are true, how is this done?
Or maybe someone can suggest another approach.

Please edit the question to let us know whether you have a negative supply available or not. It will change the complexity of the solution.

It's a shunt regulator so you can use it to regulate a negative voltage as easily as a positive one. If you don't have a negative rail then you have other problems.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
If you need both negative and positive you can use an inverting amplifier.

If this is the only way it can be done, i'll just have to create a negative voltage off the transformer to feed the TL431.

Another (often good) way is to use a charge-pump like the ICL7660 and equivalents - just one inexpensive 8 pin chip and a few capacitors.

The ICL7660 looks like a good solution. Thank you for the input.

I'd like to expand on the solution by Spehro a little. That design with R1 and R2 will produce a voltage more negative than −2.5V. R1 and R2 aren't necessary, if you can make do with −2.5V, which I'll address here.
Also, I'll talk about the value of R3, which must also be chosen with care.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
The LM317 datasheet tells us that to guarantee good regulation, the LM317 output should source at least 3.5mA (typically) at all times. See parameter "Minimum Load Current to Maintain Regulation", on page 2. The datasheet also says that this could be as bad as 10mA, so a good design would want \$I_1 >= 10mA\$ through R1. The voltage across R1 is always 1.25V, so:
$$ R_1 = \frac{1.25V}{10mA} = 125\Omega $$
I've used a nearby E12 value of 120Ω for a current \$I_1\$:
$$ I_1 = \frac{1.25V}{120\Omega} = 10.4mA $$
You'll notice I haven't used a potential divider, as you suggested. It isn't necessary because current \$I_1\$ is constant, and conveniently that means the voltage across R4 is also constant. We can therefore use a single resistance R4 to set the voltage at Y:
$$
\begin{aligned}
V_Y &=  V_X + V_{R4} \\ \\
&=  V_X + I_1R_4 \\ \\
&= -1.25V \\ \\
-1.25V &= (-2.5V) + I_1R_4 \\ \\
R_4 &= \frac{(-1.25V) - (-2.5V)}{I_1} \\ \\
&= \frac{1.25V}{10.4mA} \\ \\
&= 120\Omega \\ \\
\end{aligned}
$$
With R2 set to minimum resistance, this produces very close to 0V at the output, as shown on VM1.
You still need to be careful with R3. The TL431 datasheet tells us on page 6, parameter \$I_{MIN}\$ ("Minimum cathode current for regulation") to keep that current above 1mA. I've annotated that as \$I_2 > 1mA\$ above.
Current through R3 is the sum:
$$ I_3 = I_1 + I_2 $$
Whatever negative supply voltage you have we'll call \$V_N\$ (I've used \$V_N=-16V\$ here), and it is related by Ohm's law to current \$I_3\$ through R3:
$$ I_3 = \frac{V_X - V_N}{R_3} $$
Given that \$I_2 > 1mA\$, we have this constraint:
$$
\begin{aligned}
I_1 + I_2 &> 10.4mA + 1mA \\ \\
I_3 &> 11.4mA \\ \\
\frac{V_X - V_N}{R_3} &> 11.4mA \\ \\
R_3 &< \frac{V_X - V_N}{11.4mA} \\ \\
\end{aligned}
$$
With \$V_N=-16V\$, this gives:
$$
\begin{aligned}
R_3 &< \frac{(-2.5V) - (-16V)}{11.4mA} \\ \\
R_3 &< 1.18k\Omega \\ \\
\end{aligned}
$$

You can also use the TLV431 model if you need a voltage less than 2.5; it works identically, but with a reference voltage (minimum possible output magnitude) of 1.25 V instead.

@Hearth in which case $R_4=0\Omega$. Nice!

Looks like a great solution, thank you.


Can a TL431 be configured to output a negative ref. voltage?

If you have a voltage of -2.5V or lower (e.g. -5V) then yes.

Also, can a negative output be accomplished with a positive input to the TL431?

With the direct use of the TL431, no. But if you use a charge pump (e.g. 7660 from Intersil or Microchip) to generate a low enough negative voltage (e.g. -5V) and use TL431 along with it, yes.

I thought I could use the TL431 with a divider.

TLV431 (VREF = 1.24V) could also be an alternative.

i'll look into using the TLV431,  thank you.
